# advice needed in converting .txt array to .xml using PHPExcel

Tags: php, phpexcel

basically i need to get data.txt that consists:

```
$mas = array (
  'Adavere' => 
  array (
    '2013-04-02' => '1744',
    '2013-04-01' => '11592',
```

into xml using PHPExcel

Comment: anyone, please help me :D my brain is not functioning anymore

Comment: Please post your data.txt file and your expected xml output